# why no output when calls "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);" in Linux?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I tried to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` to run out jad app to decompile .class file. `cmd = "../bin/jad Test.class"` But I cannot get the output by this way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jadCmd2);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

nothing output, can anyone tell?

Comment: must have misread the question, removed my answer to avoid any confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are getting an error. I suggest you print that out as well.

If you use ProcessBuilder you can combine the output and error so you only have one stream to read.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

```
 ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 Process p = pb.start();
```